# err="execution timeout" timeout when calling debug_trace transaction

Tags: blockchain, transactions, json-rpc, clients, transaction-trace

I have one question.
We have organized the ethereum en node as an archive.
Since then, we have called large amounts of `debug_traceTransaction` to that node but `err="execution timeout"` occurred.

About 200 calls of `debug_traceTransactions` at a time will do well, but 10000 calls at a time will cause an error.
Do you happen to have any additional settings for the call limit or ethenode for `debug_traceTransactions`?