# "execution timeout" timeout when calling debug_trace transaction

Tags: go-ethereum, blockchain, evm, method

I have one question.
We have organized the ethereum en node as an archive. Since then, we have called large amounts of `debug_traceTransaction` to that node, but `err="execution timeout"` occurred.

About 200 calls of `debug_traceTransactions` at a time will do well, but 10000 calls at a time will cause an error. Do you happen to have any additional settings for the call limit or ethenode for `debug_traceTransactions`?

Comment: this appears to be identical to https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/158441/err-execution-timeout-timeout-when-calling-debug-trace-transaction, please don't ask the same question twice